# Spring Boot logging with Lombok

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

I would like to use [Project Lombok's log annotation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Log.html) in my Spring Boot projects but I don't want to lose the functionality of being able to change the logging from the `application.properties`.

The Spring logging docs aren't overly clear on what the default logging implementation should be used, and there are 7 Lombok choices!

Any ideas?

Comment: I use `@Slf4j(lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j)` and  I have my log settings in logback.xml. And it works pretty fine

Comment: Cool, I would like to use the config out of the box without providing any additional config though, so no `logback.xml` or anything.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I would use `@Slf4j`. Tested the following and it works as expected.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        log.info("testing logging with lombok");
    }
}
```

Then you can change the logging level as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-custom-log-levels).

```
logging.level.com.example.DemoApplication=WARN
```

Note: *Below clarifies that SLF4J is correctly handled but point is made in last 5 words!*

[From the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging):

> Default configurations are provided for Java Util Logging, Log4J2 and
> Logback." ... "By default, If you use the ‘Starters’, Logback will be
> used for logging. Appropriate Logback routing is also included to
> ensure that dependent libraries that use Java Util Logging, Commons
> Logging, Log4J or **SLF4J** will all **work correctly.**

Comment: Great, with this setup can you change the logging levels from the `application.properties` file?

Comment: So my application was not a springboot application but I was using spring framework component like JDBCTemplate for connecting to database and lombok slf4J for logging which has default logging level to DEBUG . I ended up using logback.xml file under resources/ because as per spring documentation mentioned above , it uses logback.xml for logging when used with slf4j.

Comment: My logback file looked like this : `<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref = "STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>`

Comment: The last paragraph that mentions log4j2 / logback in the first sentence.. that threw me off this answer, and I lost a day of fruitless hunting as a result. Maybe helpful to others to stress the the last five words ("SLF4J will all work correctly"). Heck, I'll try to edit to do just that..