# lombok log annotation is not working for static methods

Tags: java, lombok

I am trying to use lombok's @Slf4j annotation. It works fine for non-static methods but I am unable to use them for static ones, e.g.:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class MyClass {

    public static void staticMethod() {
        log.info(""); //build error
        //code
    }

    public void nonStaticMethod() {
        log.info(""); //builds ok
        //code
    }
```

More specifically the build error is:

```
Error:(17, 9) java: non-static variable log cannot be referenced from a static context
```

So either I am missing something or this simply is not the way to do it, but what is causing me some confusion is that [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902039/4828060) seem to indicate that this usage is the correct one. Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: but annotaion add static log , do you have additional log member?

Comment: Looks fine to me, aside from the missing } at the end. The documentation for Lombok explicitly states that `log` is static and final: https://projectlombok.org/api/lombok/extern/slf4j/Slf4j.html so this seems like a bug to me. Have you tried using another Lombok version? Aside from that, you can of course just declare "log" yourself.

Comment: I run your code it's not showing any error which version are you using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with Delombok what exactly does lombok generate in your case.

Usually the logger should be a static field.

However there is a configuration:

```
lombok.log.fieldIsStatic = [true | false] (default: true)
```

From the documentation: Normally the generated logger is a static field. By setting this key to false, the generated field will be an instance field instead.

Of course if the field is non-static you can't use it from the static method as usual in java

A [link](https://projectlombok.org/features/log) to documentation