# How to create a constant log with annotation?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

I have a project that has a specific library that has its own LogFactoring where we save information and act as we want, but in all classes I need to define:

`private static final MyLogger LOGGER = MyLoggerFactory.getLogger(MyCurrentClass.class);`

I would like to create an annotation that already creates this LOGGER constant to be used. I did several searches and didn't find it.

Comment: Does [this](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/logging/logging-with-lombok/) help?

Comment: Does this help?  [Spring Boot logging with Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43901810/3744182).