# How to inject the Log dependency to a non Mojo class instance?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there a way to inject `Log` dependency to a non-Mojo class instance? In Mojo classes, we simply call `getLog()` whenever we want to log something, but what happens in the case of a service class?

Something like this one below does not work.

```java
@Singleton
public class AServiceClass implements ServiceInterface {

    @Inject
    private Log log;
    ...
}
```

A simple way of solving this is to pass the log object from the Mojo class to the service method whenever we call it, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: why don`t you use lombok ? like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43902039/175554 I think it should work for maven plugins too

Comment: @özkanpakdil I used `AbstractLogEnabled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to [maven-checkstyle-plugin](https://github.com/apache/maven-checkstyle-plugin/blob/5d9af05c12493ba9fddf98efd74761a525c052fa/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/checkstyle/exec/DefaultCheckstyleExecutor.java#L70), I was able to find the solution.

You need to extend [AbstractLogEnabled](https://codehaus-plexus.github.io/plexus-containers/plexus-container-default/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/logging/AbstractLogEnabled.html) when you want to access the logger.

```java
@Singleton
public class AServiceClass extends AbstractLogEnabled implements ServiceInterface {

    public void method(){
        // getLogger() gives you access to the logger
        getLogger().info(...)
    }
}
```